# Finding Intervals for each Store

Tags: algorithm

You have n stores in a line, each with an associated amount of money $c_i$. At time 1, you start at store 1. At each subsequent time, you can choose to visit store i-1, stay at store i, or visit store i+1. At each time step, you can collect $c_i$ money assuming you’re at store i, regardless of how many times you already visited that store.

Given a list of times $t_j$, find the maximum amount of money that can be collected given you can collect money for $t_j$ time steps.

I’m having trouble coming up with a way to preprocess the data. My idea is that for each booth, I want to find a time interval for which it is optimal to rush straight to that booth and stay there, collecting money at each time step. I’m not sure of a correct way to do this efficiently in either O(n) time or O(nlogn) time.

Edit: What I’m currently doing is for each booth, I have an expression as a function of time that represents the maximum amount of money I can collect if I go straight to the booth and stay there. Then for each time, I take the max of all these functions. This takes linear time to process each time query. I’d like to have a logarithmic procedure for doing so.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, you are expected to show your attempt first and show where you are encountering a problem, please go through [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimum complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you know the c_i before hand or do you need to traverse through the shops to know?

Comment: The c_i are known before hand.

Comment: Is c_i independent of t_j? In other words does a c_i value for a specific shop change with t_j?

Comment: The c_i are fixed and independent of t_j.

Answer (score 0):

Your revenue function that returns the amount of money by going straight to shop `i` and staying there for a given total time `t` is

```
r_i(t) = sum(j from 1 to i - 1: c_j) + c_i * (t - i + 1)
```

The sums can be calculated incrementally for each `i` and you get a neat linear function:

```
r_i(t) = a_i + b_i * t
```

with `a_i = sum as above + (1 - i) * c_i` and `b_i = c_i`.

Now, for each time `t`, you want to find the maximum of all the `r_i(t)`. For this, we can use an ordering of the functions. Specifically, we can order them such that a function `f1` appears earlier than `f2` in an ordered sequence if function `f1` is greater than `f2` before their intersection point. Then, if we have the available functions for a given point `t` (which are all `r_i` that are reachable in `t`), we just need to step through the ordered sequence. The first element will be the best function for the starting time. Then, we can check the intersection with the next function. If `t` is after that intersection, we continue to this function as this will be the new maximum for the current interval. And so on. This can be done incrementally for each query if you sort the queries by time. While doing this process, you also need to add new functions that become available. Using an appropriate data structure (e.g. a binary search tree), you can do the insertion in O(log n).

So, how can we compare two functions `f1(t) = a1 + t * b1` and `f2(t) = a2 + t * b2`? The intersection point is `ti = (a2 - a1) / (b1 - b2)`. And `f1` is greater than `f2` before that point if `b1 < b2`.

Here is the overall algorithm:

```
input: n stores, q queries Q
sort queries by time - O(q log q)
create empty BST
currentBestFunction = empty  //pointer to element in BST
nextQuery = Q.first
sumCi = 0   //temporary variable for incremental sum
for t = 1 to maxQ
    if t <= n
        // we can reach a new store
        a = sumCi + (1 - t) * c_t
        b = c_t
        sumCi += c_t
        insert function (a, b) into BST - O(log n)
    if currentBestFunction = empty
        currentBestFunction = the inserted function
    while currentBestFunction is not the last function in BST
        successor = find successor function to currentBestFunction in BST
        calculate intersection ti = (successor.a - currentBestFunction.a) / (currentBestFunction.b - successor.b)
        if ti > t
            break //we are in the interval for the current best function
        else
            currentBestFunction = successor
    loop
    if nextQuery == t
        answer query by evaluating currentBestFunction at t
        advance nextQuery
        if no more queries then stop
```

Comment: What is the runtime for answering each query using this? And does this still apply if the queries can be bigger than n?

Comment: The runtime of answering all queries will be O(q (log q + log n)). If there are queries beyond the number of stores (sounds reasonable, didn't think of that - will update the answer accordingly), you will continue the loop but you won't add new entries to the BST.

Comment: Could you also clarify what you mean by successor function?

Comment: How is the BST sorted?

Comment: The BST contains functions. Hence, the successor function is the function that is right behind the current function in the BST ordering. The BST is ordered by the ordering relation described in the text.

Comment: How would the solution change if you cannot visit the same store two time steps in a row?

Comment: That would require a very different approach (post a new question for that). It will probably come down to a dynamic program in O(n * maxQ).